# Is it possible to automatically perform an event in java continuously?

Tags: java, swing

For example, I want a JTextfield to display different random numbers continuously with start, stop and resume buttons. What is the possible solution to automatically update the JTextField continuously when the start button is pressed?
I tried using while loop inside the start button's action listener but it just makes the button stuck in the while loop.
This is the part of the code that I tried.

```
startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            while(true){
                textField.setText(String.valueOf(random.nextInt()));
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: You need a worker thread for this as doing it in the button's action directly will block the event dispatch thread (you should read up on this too). So look for SwingWorker instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html).

You can use a `javax.swing.Timer` to change the text of the `JTextField`.

A tiny example:

```
public class TimerExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()->{
            JTextField field = new JTextField(10);

            Timer timer = new Timer(100, e->{
                field.setText(String.valueOf(Math.random()));
            });
            timer.start();

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,field);
        });
    }
}
```

If you use `while(true)` in the Thread that runs the UI (this thread is called EDT - event dispatch thread), the thread won't be able to handle events since it is stucked inside the `while` loop.

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to write it without using lamda expression? If not, how can i use non final variables in it such as count++?